# TinyMce set html content with ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I'm really stuck with a TinyMce / Jquery / Php issue and hope somebody can advise :

I have a textarea managed with TinyMce which has preloaded html content, fetched with classic database request. Everything ok till here.

Then I trigger an ajax request with jquery which either submits the textarea content in order to update it or get an alternative html content to dynamically fill it (in my case the textarea is used for multilanguage translation).

The problem is that I cannot set html content which contains html table tags () via this ajax request. It always fails. No problem with other tags. The table was previously created within the same textarea.

The method I use to append content to TinyMce textarea is :

```
            tinyMCE.get('textarea_id').focus(); 
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('html content');
```

which forks fine, except for html with tables tags.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found : have to use the php function `mysql_real_escape_string();` any other methods of escaping I tried failed

Comment: You are the MAN! Looking this for a while still not sure yet but it looks like it works for now! mysql_real_escape_string() do the trick! Thanks